# Python long-lived socket connection weirdness

Tags: python, sockets, redis

I've implemented some code that allows a client to connect to a socket server, introduces itself and the server then goes into an infinite loop which sends "commands" (strings) to the client from a Redis list. The server uses the Redis 'blpop' method to block until a string arrives which is then sent off to the client and the response awaited.

However, in testing (with a python client socket script on another local workstation) I find that if I break the client connection (Ctrl+c) to simulate an interruption in the connectivity, the server happily writes the next received string to the client, reports an empty response but ONLY throws the broken pipe exception when a second string is written :/ Thus, two writes are "lost" before anything is caught. Here's my code:

```
# Create global Redis resource
rds_cnx = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=6)

def initialise_server():
    """ Setup server socket """
    try:
        srv_skt = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        srv_skt.bind((IP, PORT))
        srv_skt.listen(1)
        print("Listening on:[{}]".format(IP, PORT))
        return srv_skt
    except socket.error as skt_err:  # e.g. port in use
        print("Could not initialise tcp server:[{}]".format(skt_err))
        sys.exit(1)
    except Exception as exp:
        print("Unable to setup server socket:[{}]".format(exp))
        sys.exit(1)


def main():

    server_socket = initialise_server()

    while True:

        client_socket, remote_address = server_socket.accept()

        try:
            # Block and wait for connection and data
            initial_data = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
            print("Connection from [{}] - Data:[{}]".format(remote_address, initial_data))

            while True:
                wait_for_queue_command(client_socket)

        except (BrokenPipeError, socket.error, Exception) as sck_exp:
            print("Exception in client loop:[{}]".format(sck_exp))
            continue
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            # Close client socket
            client_socket.shutdown(2)
            client_socket.close()
            print('Caught Ctrl+c ... Shutting down.')
            break

    # Tear down context
    server_socket.shutdown(2)  # Param ref: 0 = done receiving, 1 = done     sending, 2 = both
    server_socket.close()


def wait_for_queue_command(client_skt):
    """ Blocking while waiting for command for Redis list
    :param client_skt: socket
    :return: None
    """
    print('Waiting for command...')

    queue_cmd = rds_cnx.blpop('queuetest', 0)

    print("Received something from the queue:")
    pprint(queue_cmd)

    try:
        #client_skt.settimeout(15)
        client_skt.send(queue_cmd[1])

        # Block for response
        response_data = client_skt.recv(1024).decode()
        print("Response:[{}]".format(response_data))

    except BrokenPipeError as brkn_p:

        print('Outbound write detected "Broken Pipe":[{}]'.format(brkn_p))
        ''' Here one would decide to either re-schedule the command or 
            ignore the error and move on to the next command. A "pause"
            (sleep) could also useful? 
        '''
        raise

    except socket.timeout as sck_tmo:
        print('Socket timed out:[{}]'.format(sck_tmo))
    except socket.error as sck_err:
        print('Socket timed out:[{}]'.format(sck_err))
        raise

    print('Command handling complete.')
```

Is there any better way to handle such a situation? I've had a cursory look at Twisted but it seems very difficult to achieve the specific blocking behavior and other code that might be implemented to handle specific responses from the client.